# Probability conditional on entry of exchangeable random vector: does the index matter?

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, information-theory

I have a random varbiable $Y\in\{0,1\}$, which is dependent on a random vector $X \in \{0,1\}^n$. Therebey, the entries in $X$ are exchangeable. That is, $P(X_i=1)=P(X_j=1)$.

I want to compute/approximate $P(Y=1 | \exists j: X_j=1)$.

I know $P(Y=1 | X_1=1)$ and $P(Y=1)$. I have the intuition that $$|P(Y=1) - P(Y=1 | \exists j: X_j=1)| \leq |P(Y=1) - P(Y=1 | X_1=1)|,$$ because knowing the index of the known component of $X$ is more information than just knowing that $X_j=1$ for some index. Conditioning on more information, in turn, should change the probability more than conditioning on less information.

**Is that correct?** (Does it even hold with equality?) **Why? How could I check that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that the event $B_1 = \{X_1 = 1\}$ is a subset of the event $B_2 = \{\exists j: X_j = 1\}$ so you do "know more information", but how does that affect the probability $P(Y=1)$?  You are essentially evaluating $P(Y=1 \mid B_k)$ for three events: $B_1, B_2$, and $B_3 = \Omega$ (i.e. the entire space, i.e. unconditioned).  While it is true that $B_1 \subset B_2 \subset B_3$, the prob $P(Y=1 \mid B_k) = {P(B_k \cap Y=1) \over P(B_k)}$ depends on how the event $\{Y=1\}$ intersects with each of them, and there is no reason to believe there will be a trend.  To be more explicit, as you go from $B_1$ to $B_2$ to $B_3$, both the numerator and denominator increase (or: do not decrease), so there is no telling what can happen to the *ratio* which is $P(Y=1 \mid B_k)$.

Here is a specific counter-example.  I found myself using this as a counter-example to many different MSE questions, BTW, so this seems to be a good one to test any conjecture about conditional probabilities. :)

- $X_1, X_2 =$ two different independent fair coin flips, where $X_i = 1$ means Heads
- $Y=$ the two flips show the same result
- $P(Y=1) = {HH,TT \over HH, HT, TH, TT} = \frac12$
- $P(Y=1\mid X_1= 1) = {HH \over HH, HT} = \frac12$
- $P(Y=1 \mid X_1 =1 \cup X_2 = 1) = {HH \over HH, HT, TH} = \frac13$

Comment: +1 The example shows that "knowing that $X_j=1$ for some index" might imply "more information" that knowing $X_1=1$.

Comment: @leonbloy - you know much more information theory than me.  can you expand on that comment?  in what formal way does $B_2$ contain more information than $B_1$?

Comment: Acually I wasn't speaking in formal terms, only following the informal OP's intuition. In terms of mutual information:  letting $Z$ be the indicator variable of your event $B_2$, we see that, indeed, $I(Y;X_1)=I(Y;X_2)=0$ but $I(Y;Z)=1-\frac13 h(\frac13)>0$.
But I doubt that there is a direct relation with the OP inequalities with conditional probabilities.

Comment: ah, i see.  i know almost nothing about mutual info, but I'm _guessing_ in this case, you can conclude from  $I(Y; Z) > 0$ that $P(Y=1 \mid B_2)$ is not $1/2$ any more -- you just can't tell which way it went?  ;)